Position child control relative to parent
I have a responsive layout with a parent control and child controls, something like:

I need one of the children (Child1 in the image) to not be part of the layout, but to be positioned relative to the container. Modifying the layout is complex and it's a legacy app, I'm looking for an easy solution with minimal changes.
This is what I want:

I was able to implement the following:
void PositionRelativeToParent(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement parentElement) {
    auto pt = element.TransformToVisual(parentElement).TransformPoint(Point{0, 0});
    TranslateTransform transform;
    transform.X(-pt.X);
    element.RenderTransform(transform);
}

It works, but the problem is that because the layout is responsive, it moves to the wrong place when resized. I can set it's position with a timer, but it's a bad solution for several reasons, bad for performance and doesn't look good. But I tried it and it's the closest I could get to what I want.
How can I fix the position of Child1 to be relative to Container? Maybe I can bind it somehow?
Basically I'm looking for this: Position absolute but relative to parent, but for UWP/XAML instead of HTML/CSS.

In the absence of any XAML, the knee-jerk response is HorizontalAlignment="Left"; with a Margin of, let's say, Margin="0,96,0,0"; and a Z-Index of "last".

@GerrySchmitz Thanks, did you mean Margin="0,0,96,0"? Unfortunately it affects other items on the right. HorizontalAlignment="Left" has no effect. That's why RenderTransform could be perfect if only it could be relative to the parent, and not relative to self.

Your "green rectangle" is "left" and "down". A Margin of 0,96,0,0 is Left, Top, Right, and Bottom; meaning, push the element down 96 pixels. Whether it works or not, depends on the overall composition; i.e. the visual tree / xaml. Anything is possible; and you can usually do it 10 different ways.

@GerrySchmitz Ah, gotcha, so you assumed that HorizontalAlignment="Left" will push it to (0,0). I wish. The container is ItemsRepeater if it helps.

We can debate whether ItemsRepeater is suitable in this case. I "saw" a 2 by 2 Grid; with Child1 doing a Row and ColumnSpan of "2"; to make it "fly above".

@GerrySchmitz As I said, or at least tried to imply, the existing code and layout is a mess, no longer maintained, and I'm looking for an easy hack to make a necessary change with minimal changes.

Can adding the container to Canvas in xaml meet your needs? Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="100" 

@JunjieZhu-MSFT unfortunately some code relies on the hierarchy, I can't change it without major changes. For now I went with the timer route, I really hoped to avoid that :(
